# Custom hide/show directive on mouse over

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, mouseenter, mouseleave

From following [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) on how to build directives in Angular 2, I am trying to build my own custom directive which hides a div on mouseenter and shows it again on mouseleave. At its current state my solution don't quite work. The div flashes instead of hiding (`display: none`) completely while my mouse is moving inside of the div.

`MouseOver.directive.ts`:

```ts
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myMouseOverImage]' })

export class MouseOverImageDirective {

constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){}

@HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseenter(){
    this.mouse("none");
}


@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave(){
    this.mouse(null);
}


private mouse(dis: string){
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', dis)
    }

}
```

HTML where directive is used:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
<p myHighlight>HEllo</p>
        <div *ngFor="let displayData of data" class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12  no-padding">
            <div class="img-responsive trainer" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + displayData.imageUrl  + ')'}">
                <!--    <img  class="img-responsive"  [src]="trainer" alt="venjari"> -->
                <div  myMouseOverImage class="trainerProfileActive">

                <p> {{ displayData.name }}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use style to show hide elements: display: none; for hiding and display:block for showing.

Comment: this.mouse("none"); for hiding this.mouse("block"); for showing

Comment: As I understand your directive works as you wanted, when you mouseover div, its disappear, and at this time it means that your mouse is left div and it appears again and etc

Comment: Doesn't change anything. The div still flashes while the mouse is moving inside the div, instead of hiding completely.

Comment: The div hides when the mouse enters and appears again when the mouse leaves, but every time the mouse is moved within the div,  the div itself hides/shows repeatedly until the mouse leaves the div.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for you. Since you're hidden the entire dom element the event makes this flickering behavior. So the solution is to wrap what you want to hide with the directive use visibility style to hide the child.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myMouseOverImage]' })
export class MouseOverImageDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){}
  @HostListener('mouseover')
  onMouseenter() {
    this.mouse("hidden");
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout')
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.mouse('visible');
  }

  private mouse(dis: string) {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement.firstChild, 'visibility', dis)
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div myMouseOverImage><h2>Hello {{name}}</h2></div>
```

[Check out this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fXNxA04fcsTwn0PNjGuT?p=preview)

Comment: Works in the plunker, but when I try this in my code it does not work because firstChild is not recognized somehow

Comment: Can you create a plunker with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should better use a property like this :

```
private mouseIn: boolean = false;
private mouse(mouseIn: boolean){
    this.mouseIn = mouseIn;
}
```

And then in your template :

```
<p [hidden]="!mouseIn"> {{ displayData.name }}</p>
```

Comment: The text just disappears from the start, Also I want the div to hide, not just the <p>

Comment: So you have to play with "opacity", not "display'... Something like this :

    <div [style.opacity]="mouseIn ? 1 : 0"> {{ displayData.name }}</div>

Comment: With you input I came up with the solution. Just using opacity instead of display. When the mouse is over the div the opacity is set to 0. Else null

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseenter(){
        this.mouse("none"); // "none" to hide
    }


@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave(){
    this.mouse("block"); // "block" to show
}
```